A dynamic optimization excercise
I've got a homework question and below is my attempt. Can someone let me know if the problem can be solved within given info, or do we need something else?


What is the objective?  One might assume it is to maximise the discounted present value of the stream of output, but as currently worded that isn't stated.  And if so what is the time horizon?

@AdamBailey yes, not stated, so let's say it is to maximize the PV stream of output; and let's also say it we have the initial point is h0, end point is h1.
